# How do I use templating in MentionsInput.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mention, mentionsinput.js

> **Note:** This could be a documentation for the feature of templating the list item for the plugin [jQuery.mentionsInput](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/). So I request the users, not to close this or delete this question. TIA.

I am using [jQuery.mentionsInput](http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) in my project. Everything works fine. I am calling the plug-in using this:

```
$(".mention").mentionsInput({
    onDataRequest: function (mode, query, callback) {
        $.getJSON('/usersList', function(responseData) {
            responseData = _.filter(responseData, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 });
            callback.call(this, responseData);
        });
    }
});
```

And the source of `/usersList` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "Praveen",
        "name": "Praveen Kumar",
        "avatar": "/img/users/1.jpg",
        "type": "user"
    },
    {
        "id": "jeff",
        "name": "Jeff Atwood",
        "avatar": "/img/users/2.jpg",
        "type": "user"
    },
    {
        "id": "pekka",
        "name": "Pekka Gaiser",
        "avatar": "/img/users/3.jpg",
        "type": "user"
    },
    {
        "id": "billgates",
        "name": "Bill Gates III",
        "avatar": "/img/users/4.jpg",
        "type": "user"
    }
]
```

If you could see, there's a Full Name (`name`) and a username (`id`) associated with every user. I would like the plug-in to display the username along with the full name, so I made an amendment to the JSON like this:

```
"name": "Praveen Kumar (@Praveen)",
```

But this gives an effect like below in the textarea:

> Hello `Praveen Kumar (@Praveen)`, how are you?

Instead of displaying like:

> Hello `Praveen Kumar`, how are you?

I want this to be displayed only when the suggestion takes place and not during the insertion into the textbox. I know this can be changed using `templates`, but there's no documentation anywhere given on their website. Can someone help? I am using this:

```
templates: {
    wrapper: _.template('<div class="mentions-input-box"></div>'),
    autocompleteList: _.template('<div class="mentions-autocomplete-list"></div>')
}
```

Any heads-up on this part? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found it out. I had to do the following:

1. Add a `template` item: `autocompleteListItem`.
2. Edit the `autocompleteListItem` to include the ID by adding `(@<%= id %>)` next to the `<%= content %>`.
3. To display the search based on the ID, add the following in the `return` of the `_.filter` function.

   ```
   return (
      item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
      item.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 // Add this ID part too!
   )
   ```

Hope this is helpful to someone. Currently, I am using this code:

```
$(".mention").mentionsInput({
    onDataRequest: function (mode, query, callback) {
        $.getJSON('/usersList', function(responseData) {
            responseData = _.filter(responseData, function(item) { return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1) });
            callback.call(this, responseData);
        });
    },
    templates: {
        autocompleteListItem: _.template('<li data-ref-id="<%= id %>" data-ref-type="<%= type %>" data-display="<%= display %>"><%= content %> (@<%= id %>)</li>')
    }
});
```